# Force format for ibm mq messages

Tags: jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq

We use Spring-integration to send messages from a RabbitMQ to MQSeries. This works fine.

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="toJms" .../>
```

For some consumers we need to force the format of the ibm message or the charset
We allready use a header enricher to force some properties:

```
<int:header-enricher id="theHeaderEnricher" input-channel="fromRabbit" output-channel="toJms" >
```

How can we change the mq format and the charset of messages? Format is not a JmsHeaders but a property of the message. Can this be done with xml configuration?

Thanks for your help

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Before sending to the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` you can place a `<transformer>` in between with POJO method call and there you can do whatever you need with your reformatting.

Unfortunately it is not clear from your question how that formatting looks and what you would like to change from and into.

Therefore my answer is as generic as your question.

Please, see more info about transformer in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#messaging-transformation-chapter

Comment: Application A discuss with application B via MQSeries Channel. We replace MQSeries (A) with RabbitMQ. Spring integration works very well for simple message cases.
Some old jms publishers on A set properties (format of the mq message ...) using the ibm properties. Those properties are used during consumption on the target MQServer:

*Example of setting properties :*
`MQMessage messageMQ = new MQMessage ();
 messageMQ.format = "";messageMQ.persistence = 1;`

Do you think it would be possible in my channel jms to set those properties?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Artem.
I set a transformer before the outbound channel so i can convert the org.springframework.messaging.Message to a MQMessage with format options 

`public MQMessage transform(Message<?> msg) throws Exception`

But i have the following exception:

`Cannot convert object of type [com.ibm.mq.MQMessage] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array`

Do you have somme recommandations?

Should i use a service activator instead? this service activator would send message to mqseries?

Thanks for your help